Issue with Vanna AI Handling Multiple Schemas in the Same Database
I am working on implementing the “Talk to Data” feature using Vanna AI for our organization. As part of our setup, we are using a multi-tenant database architecture where each tenant’s data is stored in a separate schema within the same PostgreSQL database.
To accommodate this structure, I planned to create separate Vanna instances for each schema within our PostgreSQL database. Each instance is trained with a distinct training dataset specific to its corresponding schema. The intention behind this approach is to ensure that Vanna queries are schema-specific and do not cross-reference or combine data from different schemas or tenants.
However, I have encountered an issue where Vanna AI appears to be mixing up training datasets across different schemas. For example, when querying the instance that should only access Schema ‘X’, I noticed that Vanna is incorporating elements from the training data of Schema ‘Y’. This is happening even though I have explicitly trained each Vanna instance separately, ensuring that each has access only to its respective schema and training dataset.
Here’s a high-level illustration of what I’m seeing:

Schema X: Intended to have its own Vanna instance trained with only Schema X data.
Schema Y: Intended to have a separate Vanna instance trained with only Schema Y data.

But during operation, queries targeting Schema X sometimes incorrectly use patterns or insights from the Schema Y dataset and vice versa. For example:

When querying customer information from Schema X, Vanna unexpectedly references fields or entities that exist only in Schema Y.
Similarly, queries that should strictly adhere to Schema X’s context are influenced by data relationships unique to Schema Y, leading to incorrect or mixed query results.

Why is this happening? It seems that Vanna AI is not isolating the training datasets as expected, leading to cross-schema contamination in its queries.
suggest a solution to ensure that each Vanna instance operates within its defined schema boundaries without cross-referencing other schemas’ training data.
I can show you a demo code of what I did
from vanna_ai import VannaManager

# Simulated function to initialize Vanna instances for each schema
def initialize_vanna_instances(schemas):
    vanna_instances = {}
    for schema in schemas:
        # Initialize a Vanna instance for each schema
        vanna_instance = VannaManager(schema_name=schema)
        # Train each instance with the schema-specific dataset
        vanna_instance.train(training_data_path=f"/path/to/{schema}_training_data.csv")
        vanna_instances[schema] = vanna_instance
    return vanna_instances

# Simulated function to query a specific Vanna instance
def query_vanna_instance(vanna_instance, query):
    # Generate SQL using the Vanna instance
    sql_query = vanna_instance.generate_sql(question=query)
    print(f"Generated SQL for schema {vanna_instance.schema_name}: {sql_query}")
    # Run SQL query against the schema-specific database
    result = vanna_instance.run_sql(sql=sql_query)
    return result

# Initialize Vanna instances for two different schemas
schemas = ['schema_x', 'schema_y']
vanna_instances = initialize_vanna_instances(schemas)

# Example queries for different schemas
query_x = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE purchase_date > '2024-01-01';"
query_y = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_amount > 100;"

# Query the instance for schema_x
result_x = query_vanna_instance(vanna_instances['schema_x'], query_x)
print(f"Result for Schema X: {result_x}")

# Query the instance for schema_y
result_y = query_vanna_instance(vanna_instances['schema_y'], query_y)
print(f"Result for Schema Y: {result_y}")

Explanation of the Code

Initialize Vanna Instances: The initialize_vanna_instances function initializes a Vanna AI instance for each schema provided in the schemas list. Each instance is trained separately with its own schema-specific dataset.

Query Vanna Instance: The query_vanna_instance function demonstrates how a query is executed using the Vanna instance tied to a specific schema. It generates an SQL query using Vanna AI’s capabilities and runs it against the schema-specific database.

Potential Issue Illustration:
•   Schema X and Schema Y have their own Vanna instances and training datasets.
•   When querying Schema X with query_x, we expect it to only use data and context from Schema X.
•   Similarly, querying Schema Y with query_y should only reference Schema Y’s data.
•   Issue: Despite separate instances and datasets, you notice that queries are mixing data or context from different schemas.


